# MarkLogic cts:cluster Inconsistent Results

Tags: cluster-analysis, marklogic

I am trying to use the MarkLogic [`cts:cluster()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:cluster) function to create groups of documents based on their contents. It usually seems to work OK, but each time that I use the function on the same set of nodes and the same configuration, I get different clusters returned, and quite often I get a single large cluster returned, indicating that the function just gave up I guess.

My question is why do I get different results each time I use the function on the same set of nodes with the same configuration settings? There must be some third, random factor that is influencing the results, but I have not seen any mention of it, nor what its purpose might be. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the options that are being applied, and some code demonstrating how you are obtaining the nodes? Are you feeding it a consistent set of nodes?

Comment: I can guarantee the nodes are the same because I use the same XPath to access them. This is the call I am making:

cts:cluster(/SearchResultsDetails[Batch = $SelectedBatch]/Document/HitIDs, <options xmlns="cts:cluster"><overlapping>false</overlapping><num-tries>2</num-tries><max-clusters>{$MaxClusters}</max-clusters><min-clusters>{$MinClusters}</min-clusters></options>)

Comment: Note that I added the <num-tries> since I posted the question, setting it to "2" instead of the default "1", and this has at least appeared to fix the failures I was sometines getting, but I still get different responses each time I make the call.